# Titanium Terminated exit value 0 Application Installer

Tags: android, node.js, titanium, npm, appcelerator

Titanium Console.
[INFO] :   Making sure the adb server is running
[INFO] :   Removing deploy.json from SD card
[INFO] :   Installing apk: C:\androidAulaEscolar_Laboratorio\build\android\bin\Aula Escolar.apk
[INFO] :   Installing app on device: GT-S5830M

log

```html
!SESSION 2015-02-17 10:21:41.279 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_55
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=es_MX
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-02-17 10:21:45.364
!MESSAGE Warnings while parsing the images from the 'org.eclipse.ui.commandImages' extension point.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-02-17 10:21:45.364
!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='com.appcelerator.titanium.android.ui', id='com.appcelerator.titanium.mobile.command.run_on_device.android'
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2015-02-17 10:21:45.364
!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='com.appcelerator.titanium.android.ui', id='com.appcelerator.titanium.mobile.command.debug_on_device.android'

!ENTRY com.aptana.syncing.core 2 0 2015-02-17 10:21:50.553
!MESSAGE (Build 3.2.1.201402041146) [WARNING] com.aptana.syncing.core/debug Failed to load source connection point from URI file:/C:/Users/juanvilu

!ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.ide 4 0 2015-02-17 10:22:03.164
!MESSAGE (Build 3.2.1.201402041146) [ERROR] com.appcelerator.titanium.core/debug/dashboard Unknown SDK iphone

!ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.core 2 0 2015-02-17 10:23:32.446
!MESSAGE (Build 3.2.1.201402041146) [WARNING]  Failed parsing a command handler priority. Using the default priority.

Diagnostic log

Host OS: Windows 8
OS Version: 6.2
OS Arch: x86

JRE Version: 1.7.0_55
JRE Vendor: Oracle Corporation
JRE Home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7

Titanium Studio Version: 3.2.1.201402041146
Install Directory: file:/C:/Users/juanvilu/AppData/Local/Titanium Studio/
Workspace Directory: file:/C:/WorkSpace/
VM Arguments: -Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xverify:none
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Djava.class.path=C:\Users\juanvilu\AppData\Local\Titanium Studio\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar

Language: es_MX

ACS App URL: https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/apps/create.json?key=7fI2AZHmrSvAHNKsSQKzrSXz5NWjo2tt
ACS Login URL: https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/admins/studio_login.json?key=7fI2AZHmrSvAHNKsSQKzrSXz5NWjo2tt
Latest Titanium SDK: 3.2.2.GA

Titanium SDK Version: 3.1.2.GA
SDK Modules API Version:2
SDK Timestamp: 08/14/13 12:45
SDK Build Number: 5ceaff8
SDK Location: C:\Users\juanvilu\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.2.GA

Titanium SDK Version: 3.1.3.GA
SDK Modules API Version:2
SDK Timestamp: 09/18/13 12:00
SDK Build Number: 222f4d1
SDK Location: C:\Users\juanvilu\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.3.GA

Titanium SDK Version: 3.2.0.GA
SDK Modules API Version:2
SDK Timestamp: 12/20/13 10:56
SDK Build Number: d9182d6
SDK Location: C:\Users\juanvilu\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA

Titanium SDK Version: 3.2.1.GA
SDK Modules API Version:2
SDK Timestamp: 02/06/14 17:01
SDK Build Number: 991027b
SDK Location: C:\Users\juanvilu\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.1.GA

Titanium SDK Version: 3.2.2.GA
SDK Modules API Version:2
SDK Timestamp: 03/05/14 12:21
SDK Build Number: 96e9a07
SDK Location: C:\Users\juanvilu\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.2.GA

Browsers
  - Default system web browser: Unknown (N/A)
  - Internet Explorer: 9.10.9200.17228 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe)
  - Internet Explorer: 9.10.9200.17228 (C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe)
  - Mozilla Firefox: 35.0.1 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe)
  - Google Chrome: 40.0.2214.91 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
  - Opera Stable: 27.0.1689.69 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\Launcher.exe)
  - Safari: 5.34.57.2 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Safari\Safari.exe)

Android SDK Version: 4.4.2
Android NDK Version: r9d (64-bit)

Titanium CLI Enabled: true

Node.ACS Host URL: null
Node.JS Version: v0.10.13

NPM Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js

NPM Version: 1.3.2

C:\Users\juanvilu\AppData\Roaming\npm

├── acs@1.0.14

├── alloy@1.3.1

├── jade@1.1.5

├── stylus@0.42.2

└── titanium@3.2.1



npm -g ls titanium: C:\Users\juanvilu\AppData\Roaming\npm

└── titanium@3.2.1 



Packages: C:\Users\juanvilu\AppData\Roaming\npm

├─┬ acs@1.0.14

│ ├── acs-node@0.9.2

│ ├── colors@0.6.0-1

│ ├── commander@0.6.1

│ ├─┬ connect@2.3.5

│ │ ├── bytes@0.0.1

│ │ ├── cookie@0.0.4

│ │ ├── crc@0.2.0

│ │ ├── debug@0.7.4

│ │ ├── formidable@1.0.11

│ │ ├── fresh@0.0.1

│ │ ├── mime@1.2.4

│ │ ├── qs@0.4.2

│ │ └── range-parser@0.0.4

│ ├── ejs@0.8.0

│ ├── esprima@0.9.9

│ ├─┬ express@3.0.0

│ │ ├─┬ connect@2.6.0

│ │ │ ├── bytes@0.1.0

│ │ │ ├── formidable@1.0.11

│ │ │ ├── pause@0.0.1

│ │ │ ├── qs@0.5.1

│ │ │ └─┬ send@0.0.4

│ │ │   └── mime@1.2.6

│ │ ├── cookie@0.0.4

│ │ ├── crc@0.2.0

│ │ ├── debug@0.7.4

│ │ ├── fresh@0.1.0

│ │ ├── methods@0.0.1

│ │ ├── range-parser@0.0.4

│ │ └─┬ send@0.1.0

│ │   └── mime@1.2.6

│ ├─┬ fstream@0.1.18

│ │ ├── graceful-fs@1.1.14

│ │ ├── inherits@1.0.0

│ │ └── rimraf@2.2.6

│ ├─┬ jade@0.28.1

│ │ └── coffee-script@1.4.0

│ ├─┬ log4js@0.5.1

│ │ └── async@0.1.15

│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.3

│ ├── node-uuid@1.3.3

│ ├─┬ npm@1.4.4

│ │ ├── abbrev@1.0.4

│ │ ├── ansi@0.2.1

│ │ ├── ansicolors@0.3.2

│ │ ├── ansistyles@0.1.3

│ │ ├── archy@0.0.2

│ │ ├── block-stream@0.0.7

│ │ ├── child-process-close@0.1.1

│ │ ├── chmodr@0.1.0

│ │ ├── chownr@0.0.1

│ │ ├── cmd-shim@1.1.1

│ │ ├── columnify@0.1.2

│ │ ├── editor@0.0.5

│ │ ├── fstream@0.1.25

│ │ ├─┬ fstream-npm@0.1.6

│ │ │ └── fstream-ignore@0.0.7

│ │ ├── github-url-from-git@1.1.1

│ │ ├── github-url-from-username-repo@0.0.2

│ │ ├── glob@3.2.7

│ │ ├── graceful-fs@2.0.2

│ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1

│ │ ├── ini@1.1.0

│ │ ├─┬ init-package-json@0.0.14

│ │ │ └── promzard@0.2.1

│ │ ├── lockfile@0.4.2

│ │ ├── lru-cache@2.5.0

│ │ ├─┬ minimatch@0.2.14

│ │ │ └── sigmund@1.0.0

│ │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5

│ │ ├── node-gyp@0.12.2

│ │ ├── nopt@2.2.0

│ │ ├── npm-install-checks@1.0.0

│ │ ├── npm-registry-client@0.4.4

│ │ ├── npm-user-validate@0.0.3

│ │ ├─┬ npmconf@0.1.12

│ │ │ └─┬ config-chain@1.1.8

│ │ │   └── proto-list@1.2.2

│ │ ├── npmlog@0.0.6

│ │ ├── once@1.3.0

│ │ ├── opener@1.3.0

│ │ ├── osenv@0.0.3

│ │ ├── path-is-inside@1.0.0

│ │ ├─┬ read@1.0.5

│ │ │ └── mute-stream@0.0.4

│ │ ├── read-installed@1.0.0

│ │ ├─┬ read-package-json@1.1.7

│ │ │ └── normalize-package-data@0.2.9

│ │ ├─┬ request@2.30.0

│ │ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0

│ │ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.0

│ │ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.2

│ │ │ │ ├── async@0.2.9

│ │ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4

│ │ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5

│ │ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0

│ │ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2

│ │ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2

│ │ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1

│ │ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4

│ │ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0

│ │ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11

│ │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2

│ │ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2

│ │ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0

│ │ │ ├── mime@1.2.11

│ │ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1

│ │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0

│ │ │ ├── qs@0.6.6

│ │ │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@0.9.15

│ │ │ │ └── punycode@1.2.3

│ │ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0

│ │ ├── retry@0.6.0

│ │ ├── rimraf@2.2.6

│ │ ├── semver@2.2.1

│ │ ├─┬ sha@1.2.3

│ │ │ └── readable-stream@1.0.24

│ │ ├── slide@1.1.5

│ │ ├── tar@0.1.19

│ │ ├── text-table@0.2.0

│ │ ├── uid-number@0.0.5

│ │ └── which@1.0.5

│ ├── pkginfo@0.2.2

│ ├─┬ request@2.14.0

│ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.0.7

│ │ │ ├── async@0.1.22

│ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4

│ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5

│ │ └── mime@1.2.9

│ ├─┬ socket.io@0.9.16

│ │ ├── base64id@0.1.0

│ │ ├── policyfile@0.0.4

│ │ ├── redis@0.7.3

│ │ └─┬ socket.io-client@0.9.16

│ │   ├─┬ active-x-obfuscator@0.0.1

│ │   │ └── zeparser@0.0.5

│ │   ├── uglify-js@1.2.5

│ │   ├─┬ ws@0.4.31

│ │   │ ├── nan@0.3.2

│ │   │ ├── options@0.0.5

│ │   │ └── tinycolor@0.0.1

│ │   └── xmlhttprequest@1.4.2

│ ├── string@1.1.0

│ ├─┬ tar@0.1.13

│ │ ├─┬ block-stream@0.0.7

│ │ │ └── inherits@2.0.1

│ │ └── inherits@1.0.0

│ ├── temp@0.4.0

│ ├── uglify-js@1.3.2

│ ├── underscore@1.3.3

│ └── wrench@1.3.9

├─┬ alloy@1.3.1

│ ├── colors@0.6.0-1

│ ├── commander@0.6.1

│ ├─┬ jsonlint@1.5.1

│ │ ├── JSV@4.0.2

│ │ └─┬ nomnom@1.6.2

│ │   ├── colors@0.5.1

│ │   └── underscore@1.4.4

│ ├── pkginfo@0.2.2

│ ├─┬ source-map@0.1.9

│ │ └── amdefine@0.1.0

│ ├─┬ uglify-js@2.2.5

│ │ └─┬ optimist@0.3.7

│ │   └── wordwrap@0.0.2

│ ├── wrench@1.3.9

│ ├─┬ xml2tss@0.0.5

│ │ └─┬ xml2js@0.2.8

│ │   └── sax@0.5.8

│ └── xmldom@0.1.13

├─┬ jade@1.1.5

│ ├── character-parser@1.2.0

│ ├── commander@2.1.0

│ ├─┬ constantinople@1.0.2

│ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.12

│ │   ├── async@0.2.10

│ │   ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7

│ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2

│ │   ├─┬ source-map@0.1.32

│ │   │ └── amdefine@0.1.0

│ │   └── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2

│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5

│ ├─┬ monocle@1.1.51

│ │ └─┬ readdirp@0.2.5

│ │   └─┬ minimatch@0.2.14

│ │     ├── lru-cache@2.5.0

│ │     └── sigmund@1.0.0

│ ├─┬ transformers@2.1.0

│ │ ├─┬ css@1.0.8

│ │ │ ├── css-parse@1.0.4

│ │ │ └── css-stringify@1.0.5

│ │ ├─┬ promise@2.0.0

│ │ │ └── is-promise@1.0.0

│ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.2.5

│ │   ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7

│ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2

│ │   └─┬ source-map@0.1.32

│ │     └── amdefine@0.1.0

│ └─┬ with@2.0.0

│   └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.0

│     ├── async@0.2.10

│     ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7

│     │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2

│     ├─┬ source-map@0.1.32

│     │ └── amdefine@0.1.0

│     └── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2

├─┬ stylus@0.42.2

│ ├── css-parse@1.7.0

│ ├── debug@0.7.4

│ ├─┬ glob@3.2.8

│ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1

│ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.14

│ │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0

│ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0

│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5

│ └── sax@0.5.8

└─┬ titanium@3.2.1

  ├── async@0.2.10

  ├── colors@0.6.2

  ├─┬ fields@0.1.12

  │ └── keypress@0.1.0

  ├── humanize@0.0.9

  ├─┬ jade@0.35.0

  │ ├── character-parser@1.2.0

  │ ├── commander@2.0.0

  │ ├─┬ constantinople@1.0.2

  │ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.12

  │ │   ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7

  │ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2

  │ │   ├─┬ source-map@0.1.32

  │ │   │ └── amdefine@0.1.0

  │ │   └── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2

  │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5

  │ ├─┬ monocle@1.1.50

  │ │ └─┬ readdirp@0.2.5

  │ │   └─┬ minimatch@0.2.14

  │ │     ├── lru-cache@2.5.0

  │ │     └── sigmund@1.0.0

  │ ├─┬ transformers@2.1.0

  │ │ ├─┬ css@1.0.8

  │ │ │ ├── css-parse@1.0.4

  │ │ │ └── css-stringify@1.0.5

  │ │ ├─┬ promise@2.0.0

  │ │ │ └── is-promise@1.0.0

  │ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.2.5

  │ │   ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7

  │ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2

  │ │   └─┬ source-map@0.1.32

  │ │     └── amdefine@0.1.0

  │ └─┬ with@1.1.1

  │   └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.0

  │     ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7

  │     │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2

  │     ├─┬ source-map@0.1.32

  │     │ └── amdefine@0.1.0

  │     └── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2

  ├── longjohn@0.2.2

  ├── moment@2.4.0

  ├─┬ node-appc@0.2.0

  │ ├── adm-zip@0.4.4

  │ ├── diff@1.0.8

  │ ├─┬ dox@0.4.4

  │ │ ├── commander@0.6.1

  │ │ └── github-flavored-markdown@1.0.1

  │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1

  │ ├── semver@2.1.0

  │ ├─┬ uglify-js@2.3.6

  │ │ ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7

  │ │ │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2

  │ │ └─┬ source-map@0.1.32

  │ │   └── amdefine@0.1.0

  │ └── xmldom@0.1.19

  ├─┬ optimist@0.6.1

  │ ├── minimist@0.0.7

  │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2

  ├─┬ request@2.27.0

  │ ├── aws-sign@0.3.0

  │ ├── cookie-jar@0.3.0

  │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2

  │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.2

  │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4

  │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5

  │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0

  │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2

  │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2

  │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1

  │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4

  │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0

  │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11

  │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2

  │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2

  │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0

  │ ├── mime@1.2.11

  │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1

  │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0

  │ ├── qs@0.6.6

  │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0

  ├── semver@2.2.1

  ├── sprintf@0.1.3

  ├─┬ temp@0.6.0

  │ ├── osenv@0.0.3

  │ └─┬ rimraf@2.1.4

  │   └── graceful-fs@1.2.3

  ├─┬ winston@0.6.2

  │ ├── async@0.1.22

  │ ├── cycle@1.0.3

  │ ├── eyes@0.1.8

  │ ├── pkginfo@0.2.3

  │ ├── request@2.9.203

  │ └── stack-trace@0.0.8

  └── wrench@1.5.7



NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX env value: null

Npm config prefix value : C:\Users\juanvilu\AppData\Roaming\npm


ENV:
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\juanvilu
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMFILES%\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
Path_v2=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\android-sdk\tools;C:\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared
SystemDrive=C:
TEMP=C:\Users\juanvilu\AppData\Local\Temp
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)
Path=C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\android-sdk\tools;C:\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Users\juanvilu\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\android-sdk\tools;C:\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\android-sdk\tools;C:\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Users\juanvilu\AppData\Local\Titanium Studio;
HOMEDRIVE=C:
PROCESSOR_REVISION=3a09
USERDOMAIN=dev-juanvilu-w8
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
android_sdk=c:\android-sdk
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
SESSIONNAME=Console
TMP=C:\Users\juanvilu\AppData\Local\Temp
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
LOGONSERVER=\\DEV-JUANVILU-W8
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=AMD64
OS=Windows_NT
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
HOMEPATH=\Users\juanvilu
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=dev-juanvilu-w8
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\juanvilu\AppData\Local
COMPUTERNAME=DEV-JUANVILU-W8
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
windir=C:\Windows
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4
PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
USERNAME=juanvilu
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
APPDATA=C:\Users\juanvilu\AppData\Roaming
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that you have the compatible build-tool folder, like r20. It must be compatible with the SDK tool which you are using to build. For example 3.5.0.GA can be build using r21.